# Connection Problems Powerbook G4 lubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu

Ok, I've been scouring the various message boards with little success in addressing this issue.

I have an old PowerBook G4, and I'm having trouble with the wireless.

The card is active, I can see the wireless networks in Network Manager, but when I attempt to connect, it just repeatedly asks me for the network password, which I know to be correct.

I haven't been able to find a clear fix for this so far.
Any thoughts?

Output from wireless info script below

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Oct 2017 13:29 EDT -0400

Booted last: 24 Oct 2017 11:41 EDT -0400

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-97-powerpc-smp #120~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 20 15:54:00 UTC 2017 ppc ppc ppc GNU/Linux

, ro, quiet, splash, radeon.agpmode=-1, 

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

0001:24:0f.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Apple Inc. UniNorth GMAC (Sun GEM) [106b:0021] (rev 01)
    Kernel driver in use: gem

ff08:00:0b.0 Host bridge [0600]: Apple Inc. UniNorth 1.5 AGP [106b:002d]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

PRODID_1=""
PRODID_2=""
PRODID_3=""
PRODID_4=""
MANFID=0000,0000
FUNCID=255

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

airport                 3709  0 
orinoco                73480  1 airport
cfg80211              499172  1 orinoco

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
wpa-essid JSNET
wpa-psk <WPA key removed>

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth1' [IF2]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.14  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth1' [IF2]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:24034 errors:6 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:6
          TX packets:21838 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:17031980 (17.0 MB)  TX bytes:2598946 (2.5 MB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth2' [IF3]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:57 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:462 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:35977 (35.9 KB)  TX bytes:35977 (35.9 KB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth1      no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth2      IEEE 802.11b  ESSID:""  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: None   
          Bit Rate:11 Mb/s   Sensitivity:1/0  
          Retry short  long limit:8   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=0/70  Signal level=-122 dBm  Noise level=-122 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:44
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth1

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager
    Wicd

Running:

root      2804     1  0 11:54 ?        00:00:04 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth1  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            ax88179_178a
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth1' [IF2]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.14
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            gem
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

- Device: eth2 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            airport
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth2' [IF3]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    The Smokehouse:  Infra, <MAC 'The Smokehouse' [AN1]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 29 WPA2
    JSNET:           Infra, <MAC 'JSNET' [AC1]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 69 WPA WPA2
    DIRECT-6C-HP OfficeJet 3830: Infra, <MAC 'DIRECT-6C-HP OfficeJet 3830' [AN3]>, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 9 WPA2
    PRPTCO:          Infra, <MAC 'PRPTCO' [AN4]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 25 WPA2
    xfinitywifi:     Infra, <MAC 'xfinitywifi' [AN5]>, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27
    LatoyaNet:       Infra, <MAC 'LatoyaNet' [AN6]>, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 15 WPA WPA2

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JSNET]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JSNET | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JSNET | mac-address=<MAC 'eth2' [IF3]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JSNET
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth1      no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

eth2      11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth1      Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)

eth2      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'JSNET' [AC1]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"JSNET"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00000000ec1fa370
                    Extra: Last beacon: 164ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[airport]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-97-powerpc-smp/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/orinoco/airport.ko
license:        Dual MPL/GPL
description:    Driver for the Apple Airport wireless card.
author:         Benjamin Herrenschmidt <benh@kernel.crashing.org>
srcversion:     21052957383B9E0FA798721
depends:        orinoco
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-97-powerpc-smp SMP mod_unload modversions 

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-97-powerpc-smp/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     4B104D07EC5684C9E39533C
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-97-powerpc-smp SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

airport
apm_emu
snd-powermac

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.local.conf]
blacklist snd-aoa-codec-tas
blacklist snd-aoa-fabric-layout
blacklist snd-aoa-i2sbus
blacklist snd-aoa-soundbus
blacklist snd-aoa

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x106b:0x0021 (gem)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# USB device 0x:0x (ax88179_178a)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth1' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
# PCI device 0x106b:0x0022 (airport)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth2' [IF3]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"

##### dmesg #############################

[   46.755846] eth2: Lucent/Agere firmware doesn't support manual roaming (repeated 6 times)
[  170.574540] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  170.781065] eth2: Lucent/Agere firmware doesn't support manual roaming
[  172.315356] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1 (repeated 2 times)
[  172.364473] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[  173.097636] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[  183.960530] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  183.963247] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
[  184.688464] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  186.587203] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1 (repeated 2 times)
[  186.636310] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[  347.647533] gem 0001:24:0f.0 eth0: Found BCM5421 PHY
[  347.648021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  943.581125] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[  944.025669] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  944.052979] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
[  944.149675] gem 0001:24:0f.0 eth0: Found BCM5421 PHY
[  944.150172] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  945.682478] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1 (repeated 2 times)
[  945.731632] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[  946.997214] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[  948.997618] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  949.010439] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1
[  950.425613] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  951.680984] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[  952.114401] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1 (repeated 2 times)
[  952.163568] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[  952.229156] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth2: link is not ready
[  953.701565] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[  953.714386] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1 (repeated 3 times)
[  955.493509] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[  956.465192] eth2: Lucent/Agere firmware doesn't support manual roaming (repeated 5 times)
[ 1099.703614] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: unregister 'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:10:18.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet
[ 1099.703672] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: Failed to read reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 1099.703687] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 1099.725330] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 1099.725354] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0001: -19
[ 1099.725367] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1 (unregistered): Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 1100.650450] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: register 'ax88179_178a' at usb-0000:10:18.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, <MAC 'eth1' [IF2]>
[ 1101.213773] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[ 1102.864570] ax88179_178a 1-1:1.0 eth1: ax88179 - Link status is: 1 (repeated 2 times)
[ 1102.913922] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
[ 2300.141473] eth2: Lucent/Agere firmware doesn't support manual roaming (repeated 10 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

iw list | grep -A7 Ciphers
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed

Comment: Added the requested output from the script.

Comment: The interesting bit is the log entry “Lucent/Agere firmware doesn't support manual roaming.” I'd try a few different kernels because some people reported regressions like this. Could you please try the v3.13 kernel branch shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? If that doesn't work try live systems with 16.04 and 17.04.

Comment: Other than that https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/orinoco claims that this driver requires a particular setting in `wpa_supplicant` which NetworkManager uses: create a file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` if it doesn't exist and add the entry `ap_scan=2` (or replace the `ap_scan` entry if it exists already).

Comment: …you need to restart NetworkManager or reboot for the previous changes to take effect. Some chipsets operated by this driver also don't support WPA2 encryption. Could you please try all of the above with an unencrypted wireless network?

Comment: I can tell you that without making any changes I could successfully connect to non encrypted networks. I'll run through your recommended fixes and see what happens, thanks!

Comment: That's an excellent hint! One of the other suggestions *may* work, but it's likely that nothing but a firmware update will allow association with WPA2-encrypted networks (if the manufacturer provides one because as far I remember and understand the wireless kernel wiki, there's none). In that case you can either (1) switch to WPA although that has been superseded because of security flaws in its protocol design or, (2) better, buy a different, add-on wireless adapter that is supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: The USB-v1.1 ports on the Powerbook G4 are crap unless you can live with 12 MBit/s top speed (half-duplex), but it can apparently take [PC Cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_Card) of Type I and II ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=PowerBook_G4&oldid=804139804#Models_2), see the “Peripherals” row) of which there are many to choose from. You can search or ask for recommendations of suitable PC Cards (also called PCMCIA) over on [HardwareRecs.SE].

Comment: There's also a Ubuntu Community Help Wiki with [wireless adapters known to work](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported) classified by interface type including PCMCIA.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `iw list | grep -A7 Ciphers` I suspect that the orinoco hardware and driver only support open networks and WEP.

Comment: It looks like chili 555 may be correct.  Probably my best bet is to change hardware or just get used to being tethered to the wall.....